# Do I need to invalidate my NSTimer before calling popToRootViewController?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have one UInavigationController and three UIViewControllers.

Let's call them nav, vcA, vcB and vcC.

nav contains vcA as root, and pushes vcB and then vcC.

I have a NSTimer at vcC and I called the function popToRootViewController.

**NSTimer is working, even I'm at vcA (root of nav). Do I need to invalidate it in order to vcC releases?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate NSTimer, do you set `self` (vcC) as its target? If so then you need to invalidate your timer or else vcC won't be released. I don't know how familiar you are with ARC, but when you set vcC as NSTimer's target, [vcC's retain count is added by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4915138/6543229)

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. I added the invalidate at **viewWillDisappear** method

Answer (score 1):

If the timer is a

- **repeating** timer it's good programming habit to invalidate the timer.
- **single shot** timer it invalidates itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tips